# Download Eclipse with no packages?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to download eclipse with no packages added onto it (only the plain text editor and basic features). This way I can only install the packages that I know I will use, and keep it minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Go to http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ and click on the version/build you want.  You're looking for the **Platform Runtime Binary** download for your platform.